# Problem while concatenating two numpy arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

My aim is to rotate a 1d numpy array by left.For example desired output for numpy array `[1,2,3,4]` should be `[2,3,4,1]`.

Here is my approach:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
x1 = x[1:]
x2 = x[:1]
print(np.concatenate(x1,x2))
```

I am facing an error while concatenating. Why is that?

I tried this approach also:

```py
lst = x[1:] + x[:1]
print(np.array(lst))
```

Although I am getting the desired output I am also getting a error

`DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.`

Comment: extra pair of brackets? `np.concatenate([x1,x2])`

Comment: @PaulPanzer Oh yeah silly me.That was the problem

Answer (score 1):

I already saw this kind of problem to build AES in python. But I didn't used numpy, only list: the step is called **ShiftRows**

Anyway, you can use: **np.roll(your_array, int_shift)**
For example:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> shift_x = np.roll(x, 3)
>>> shift_x
>>> array([2, 3, 4, 1])
```